# Two-way beautifier integration with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

We have a very diverse team of developers. Each developer prefers a very different source code indentation and formatting style. Beautifier/pretty printer tools exist that can output in each of these developers' preferred styles. Our code is stored in a Mercurial repository in a standard formatting style, using a commit hook.

However, I would like to go a bit further. Is it possible to beautify the source code into the developer's preferred style when he clones/pulls/updates his workspace? That way, he would see all code in his preferred style. When he/she commits the code gets beautified back into the standard formatting style of the central repository.

Is there a hook I can use to beautify files before being updated/checked out?

How would that work during merging? Can the others files we are merging against also be beautified using a chosen style (as to minimize the amount of conflicts)?

Comment: Working in C++ for >15 years I had to work in projects with a bewildering variety of coding and formatting styles. My conclusion is this: It's all vanity. As a professional programmer, look at the style a project has settled on, and adapt to use that style whenever you are reading and writing source code in that project. I mean see the point in code beautification before you checkin, but, really, for _reading_ code?! Unless the style is really outragingly unreadable (I've known a programmer who put spaces around _every_ operator), I'd say grow up and learn to read.

Comment: @sbi, we have team members writing indeed whitespace around every operator, others prefer tab-characters in their source, K&R, Horstmann style, etc. So styles vary wildly, and reviewing each others code (where you need to be very precise and don't overlook a brace) takes more effort due to the mental context-switching each time. Hence, my wish to present the codebase to each of the team members in their own style.

Comment: Reviewing code is about design, algorithms, data structures.. certainly not about braces. In that case most experienced programmers can overlook the particular coding style, and focus on the things that actually matter.

Comment: If you do choose to go down this path, check out the [eol extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EolExtension), it does something significantly simpler (which is not easy on its own) and that's to have a uniform line ending in the repository but a custom one on checkouts.

Comment: @JoseCeale: But I was arguing in favor of settling for one formatting style and have everybody stick to it. You are grown up, I presume, so you won't need to haggle about it for longer than an hour or two.

Comment: @IdanK: thanks for pointing out the EolExtension. It appears it does text transformation in the same places a beautifier would go.

Comment: The comments with respect to adapting to the style of the project and growing up, are perfectly valid. However, wouldn't it be nice if everybody could just work in their preferred style, be slightly happier, slightly more productive, etc.? On a technical level, this should be possible since everybody has his own workspace and sandbox. Unless there are significant performance penalties or awkward workarounds needed, I don't see why we shouldn't give this a try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way (in theory) to implement that would be through [encode/decode filters](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EncodeDecodeFilter), but I don't think it is worth it, because of all the potential side-effects.

It is best to have some kind of format reinforcement in a centralized place, reject any push to a centralized repo if said centralized repo detects code incorrectly formatted.
That reminds the coder to use the "official" (and unique) code format in place for the current project.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using encode/decode filters and it works perfectly. Even merges are presented by my diff-tool in my preferred indentation style.

Comment: could you please elaborate on "potential side-effects"?

Comment: @Jose: I don't have much experience with those filters, so I ma not sure of what will happen when switching branches or pulling new content from a remote repo as regard to your existing working tree (with its content currently filtered)